# VB.NET Numeric type only generics?

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface, casting, primitive-types

VB.NET, .NET 4

Hello all,

Suppose I have an interface called IParseable(Of TParsed, TUnparsed) which requires two functions:

```
Function Parse(ByVal Value As TUnparsed) As TParsed
Function Unparse(ByVal Value As TParsed) As TUnparsed
```

Is there a way that I can restrict TParsed and TUnparsed to be numeric types (for which operations like "*" and "+" are already defined)?

The problem is that, when I try to implement my interface and define one of the functions, e.g.:

```
Public Function Parse(ByVal Value As TUnparsed) As TParsed Implements IParseable(Of TParsed, TUnparsed).Parse
   Return CType(10 * Value, TParsed)
End Function
```

VS throws an error saying the "*" is not defined for TUnparsed.  I understand that, since TUnparsed could be anything, but is there a way to restrict my generic such that, say, TUnparsed could only be Double, Integer, Long, etc?

I ask this because I know that you can do something like:

```
Function Blah(Of T As TextBox)(ByVal Control As T) As Object
```

To require Control to be a TextBox (or maybe I don't understand that very well either....).  But, anyway, any idea or am I way off track?  Just trying to get a hang of these interface thingies and generic types.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

There are [two](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GenericArithmeticUtil.aspx) [workarounds](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html).

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to mention (in case anyone is wondering something similar) that, while SLaks is right regarding the arithmetic, I read about a neat way to restrict the generic to comparable value types:

(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})